# Showing narrow lists on android tablets

Tags: android, listview, scroll, tablet

I'm working on an android app with a number of lists containing tweets/user bios which currently expand to the full width of the device.

E.g.:

```
--------------------------------------
Hello, My name is Tom and I am trying
to make a nice UI
                                reply
--------------------------------------
Hello, My you are awesome and I am 
hoping you will be able to help
                                reply
--------------------------------------
```

When looking at these in landscape mode, especially on tablets, the list stretches to the full width of the tablet, causing the content to stretch also, making it hard to read.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Hello, My name is Tom and I am trying to make a nice UI                         |
|                                                                          reply |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Hello, My you are awesome and I am hoping you will be able to help              |
|                                                                          reply |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want to add margin down each side of the list, and a border between the list and the margin, while keeping the rest of the app full-width.

```
               |--------------------------------------|
               |Hello, My name is Tom and I am trying |
               |to make a nice UI                     |
               |                                reply |
               |--------------------------------------|
               |Hello, My you are awesome and I am    |
               |hoping you will be able to help       |
               |                                reply |
               |--------------------------------------|
```

Simple enough, except that when I use margin, touch events beyond the border do not effect the list. This means if a user is trying to scroll while touching the margins, the list does not scroll.

An alternative solution is to use padding, which allows scroll, but then I cannot add a border.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can use `layout_weight` property and divide the screen into 3 parts.

Comment: So, create two more views for left/right margin? How would you manage the scroll issues?

Comment: Basically, divide the screen into 3 parts. The middle part will be the listview. What scroll issues are you having? Is is that you want the whole screen to be scrollable?

Comment: When you try to scroll down the list, if you're not touching list, the list doesn't scroll. See update for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use layout_weight along with empty elements, and a RelativeLayout to achieve the same effects as margins.

Comment: I don't think that'll solve the scrolling problem - I want to acheive the same affect as padding, with borders on the inside edge.